# Compass Scss + Blueprint : setting overflow

Tags: css, compass-sass, sass, blueprint-css

I am using blueprint via Compass but have no scroll bars on longer pages, it seems the default overflow is set to 'hidden'. This is the default so I am guessing there is some method/structure everyone else is using apart from me. If not how do I set 'overflow:scroll'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So did a bit of firebug research and it seems people don't use one main container for the site but use it in separate bits so then the best method is to set the divs you do want to have a scroll in to overflow:visable.

e.g. you might have div#main which you then set to overflow but your div#pageHeader you can leave as overflow hidden